# Routing through no connect pins in Altium?

Tags: altium, routing, bga

I have an 0.5mm pitch BGA part I'm trying to route in Altium. The datasheet specifically calls out a number of balls on the part as having "no internal connection" and I've seen at least one manufacturer design guide that shows traces going through these pads as a way of having to avoid trying to do a via-in-pad or finding a place to stick a via within the ball grid.

My question is, what's the best way to handle this in Altium? I could just force certain pads to belong to the net I want to route through them but I'd rather have a rule that allows "any net" to be connected to a pad. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Edit:
The suggestion to force pins I want to route through to have a certain net is, I think, a good one because it forces me to make my intentions clear to the rule checker.

A follow-up question would be: is there a good way to force certain pins to NEVER be routed? For example, some pins are called out as "RFU (reserved for future use)" and I want to make sure these are never used. I tried making them all belong to a net class and making a clearance rule for that class, but it's still easy to force one of these pins to belong to a net and then route to it without the DRC complaining.

Comment: I think best practice would still be to associate that copper with a net. Otherwise, the rules checks wouldn't know if you meant for a particular net to actually hit that pad, or if something that was 1 mil away was truly violating clearance.

Comment: @scld: That seems like a pretty safe way to go and is probably what I'll end up doing. Thanks.

Comment: @CodingHero keep in mind that you will be ultimately responsible for issues if manufacturer will change pin assignment from N.C. to something else in next or current versions of chip.

Comment: @Anonymous You're absolutely right, this is a risk. I think the best I can do is to add schematic/BOM documentation to be sure to carefully check pinouts and datasheets before using a new part.

Comment: I would advise doing two routings - using NC pins and without using them, and analyze benefits in both scenarios. The issue is people do not like to read documentation... thus even best docs are being read only when something fries... three times! Good luck!